# .NET Core WebJob Console App CI/CD using Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build my console application through Azure DevOps. So to this I'm following [this tutorial](https://subhankarsarkar.com/dotnet-core-webjob-console-app-ci-cd-using-azure-devops-pipelines/).

The follow images, are from what I already did.

**Build Solution Pipeline**
[image]

**Build Solution Pipeline / Publish**
[image]

**Build Solution Pipeline / Artifact**
[image]

**Deploy WebJob Pipeline**
[image]

**Deploy WebJob Pipeline / Variables**
[image]

When I run the **Build Solution** the zip seems to work, because I see it.

[image]

But when I run the **Deploy WebJob Pipeline** I get `##[error]D:\a\1\s\***.zip not found.`. I tried `wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/`, but still the same error.

What could I be doing wrong? What's the right way to set the `zippedArtifactPath`?

Comment: You're using a build pipeline to try to release. Use a release, not a build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're following the tutorial incorrectly. The tutorial is telling you to create a release. You're using a build pipeline to try to release. Although you *can* do that, you *shouldn't*.

You have two options:

- If you want to keep using the visual designer, use a release. Look at the "Release" tab for this. Releases can be tied to build artifacts and will handle downloading the build artifact automatically.
- If you want to use YAML, refer to the YAML documentation and set up a multi-stage pipeline to release.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Daniel! Indeed I should be in Releases (not Pipelines). And about the `zippedArtifactPath` it will be the Artifact `Source alias` (set in the release pipeline page).

Answer (score 1):

> What could I be doing wrong?

Check your error messgae `##[error]D:\a\1\s\***.zip not found` we can find in the `second` build pipeline, the PS tried to get the xx.zip in `xxx\s` folder while in `first` build pipeline you published the xx.zip to `xxx\a` folder.

The [$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables) for build pipeline is `xx\s` folder while [that for release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#system-variables) is `xx\a` folder. In first build pipeline we published the xx.zip to [Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#system-variables) which is a `xx\a` folder, so we can't access the xx.zip from `xx\s` folder in second build pipeline's PS script.

> What's the right way to set the zippedArtifactPath?

It's not recommended to build and deploy one web app using two build pipelines. For normal logic, we should do this by using combination like build+release pipeline just like the [Toturial](https://subhankarsarkar.com/dotnet-core-webjob-console-app-ci-cd-using-azure-devops-pipelines/) and **Daniel** suggests above.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this variable $(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias) to get the artifact directory.
In your powerShell script you can set path variable like:

```
$path = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)\webjobs_drop\[ZIP_File_Name].zip"
```

Answer (score -1):

[your build artifact name]\webjobs_drop[your zipped files].zip

"your build artifact name" - you should get it from your release pipelines Artifacts stage from where you are selecting your build artifacts

Comment: When I access the `Artifacts` from the menu. I get `No packages have been promoted to this release view`. But I also see my username in the `Organization scopes feeds` Could my `build artifact name` be my username?

Comment: Anyway, it's not my username, because it did not work.

Comment: I feel that I'm missing some step, just don't know which.